# Android OpenCV Setup

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv, installation

I am trying to setup eclipse for making a computer vision application for android platform using OpenCV. But i am continuously getting error:
"The application testOpenCV (process.edu.stanford.android) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again."
while simulating the application.
I followed may tutorials for this but couldn't get it running correct.
The quoted error was when i followed the steps given on
http://www.stanford.edu/~zxwang/android_opencv.html
Please help me as i am failed to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Would be nice if you give a little more information. The error "The application testOpenCV (process.edu.stanford.android) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again." is what you always get when you try and run an app that has errors, and doesn't provide any information of these errors at all. There is a thing called logcat in Eclipse which give more detailed information about your errors.

However I suggest you rebuild everything from scratch and follow the tutorial from this site:
**http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_binary_package.html**

It also comes with some samples which you can use and if you want, 2 of these samples use C/C++ code by using JNI calls.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [good tutorial](http://bsd-noobz.com/opencv-guide/32-3-set-up-opencv-in-eclipse) where you can find the steps to setup OpenCV with Eclipse. Also if you want [tutorials to setup openCV on different OS](http://www.intorobotics.com/tutorials-setup-opencv-for-android-ios-linux-and-windows/) click on the above link